# Can I keep UI elements accessable while changing background color in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uianimation

I have a game in Xcode with several UIButtons over white background. When the user clicks correct buttons, I'm changing the background from white to blue-green (animated). I'd like to allow the user to keep clicking, while the background colors change, but it looks like the buttons are not accessible until the bg color animation is done running. 
Is there a way to resolve it and keep the focus on the buttons? Can the background animation happen in the background, independent of the rest of the game?

Thanks in advance for any help with understanding this. 
Here is my code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
animations:^{
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.1f green:0.15f blue:0.05f alpha:1.0f];
}
completion:^(BOOL finished){
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
animations:^{
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0f];
}
];
}
];
```

All UIButtons are added in a separate method earlier

```
UIButton *btnI;
[self.view addSubview:btnI];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use animation method with [options](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion:):

```
+ animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:
```

with *UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction* option.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:):

```
If you want users to be able to interact with the views, include the   UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction constant in the options parameter.
```

Comment: Thank you! The UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score -1):

use

```
dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, {
//change the background colour here
})
```

Comment: Changing backgroundColor in the background thread  is not good idea.

Comment: but he need  forground  state active while back ground color change animation in process. may be it has a slow animation.

Comment: He need interaction wile animation in progress, it is different. Changing of the background colour it not complicated operation, but animation engine can block user interactions.

Comment: if we change the color on background thread than our main thread is free the interaction is working fine on main thread.

Comment: Here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/ , you can read about thread interaction and UIView in the part "Threading Considerations"